# How to find where coin was picked up

Tags: blockchain

I just recently sent two transactions at $2,500 a piece to a wallet I was given to transfer the money to. The money was transferred and the person has disappeared. I'm wondering how to find out where the money was picked up at.

Answer (score 2):

> **how to find out where the money was picked up**

You can't.

Bitcoin was designed with privacy in mind.

Comment: If you're working for a police agency, you may be able to.  If you're working for the CIA or an equivalent national intelligence service, you probably can.  Bitcoin was designed with *pseudonymitiy* in mind, not *anonymity*, so you can freely track the flow of money through the network.  You generally need government-level investigative powers to track money as it enters or leaves the network.